# Check for special characters in a string using regex in java

Tags: java, android, regex

How to check for special chars in a string? I am checking for just empty spaces using regex but when i enter special chars it's considering them as space. Below is my code

```
  private boolean emptySpacecheck(String msg){

    return msg.matches(".*\\w.*");
}
```

How to check for special chars?

Comment: White space is `\s` not `\w`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Pattern matcher for check special character and you can check below example:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]");

if (regex.matcher(your_string).find()) {
    Log.d("TTT, "SPECIAL CHARS FOUND");
    return;
}
```

Hope this helps you...if you need any help you can ask

Answer (score 3):

> An easy way is to check if a string has any non-alphanumeric
>   characters.

**TRY THIS,**

*StringChecker.java*

```
public class StringChecker {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String str = "abc$def^ghi#jkl";

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

      System.out.println(str);
      int count = 0;
      while (m.find()) {
         count = count+1;
         System.out.println("position "  + m.start() + ": " + str.charAt(m.start()));
      }
      System.out.println("There are " + count + " special characters");
   }
}
```

**And you get the result look like below:**

```
$ java SpecialChars
abc$def^ghi#jkl
position 3: $
position 7: ^
position 11: #
There are 3 special characters
```

> You can pass your own patterns as param in compile methods as per your needs
>   to checking special characters:
>
> ```
> Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]");
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> *...when i enter special chars it's considering them as space.*

Which means you only want to check whether String contains space or not.

You don't need regular expression to check for space. You can simply call [`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method.

```
private boolean emptySpacecheck(String msg){
    return msg != null && msg.contains(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following RegExp:

```
private boolean emptySpacecheck(String msg){
    return msg.matches(".*\\s+.*");
}
```

- `\s` matches with these characters: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

Try it online: https://regex101.com/r/GztOoI/1